# rules in .prettierrc.json are not automatically updated

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

I'm using a setup with prettier + eslint in my node project.

My problem is when I want to add/change some rules in my .prettierrc.file, I can't see the changes automatically.

To see the new changes, I have to restart my visual studio code project.

My files:

.prettierrc.json

```
{
  "trailingComma": "none",
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "semi": false,
  "comma-dangle": false,
  "printWidth": 100
}
```

.eslintrc.json

```
{
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "node": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "extends": ["standard", "plugin:prettier/recommended"],
  "plugins": [
    "prettier"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2020
  },
  "rules": {
    "camelcase":"off",
    "import/order": ["warn", {
      "pathGroups": [{
        "pattern": "~/**",
        "group": "external",
        "position": "after"
      }],
      "newlines-between": "always"
    }],
    "padding-line-between-statements": [
      "error",
      {"blankLine": "always", "prev": "*", "next": "return"},
      {"blankLine": "always", "prev": ["const", "let", "var"], "next": "*"},
      {"blankLine": "any", "prev": ["const", "let", "var"], "next": ["const", "let", "var"]}
    ]
  }
}
```

dependencies

```
{
  "eslint": "^6.8.0",
  "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.15.0",
  "eslint-config-standard": "^14.1.0",
  "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.0",
  "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.0.0",
  "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
  "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
  "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.1",
  "prettier": "^2.1.2"
}
```

my vsc settings

```
{
    "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Owlet (Oceanic Next)",
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/bin/zsh",
    "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
    "git.confirmSync": false,
    "window.restoreWindows": "one",
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "editor.fontFamily": "Fira Code , Menlo, Monaco, 'Courier New', monospace",
    "editor.fontLigatures": true,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "[typescript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "extensions.ignoreRecommendations": false,
    "explorer.openEditors.visible": 0,
    "eslint.workingDirectories": [
        "./{PATH_TO_CLIENT}"
    ],
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll.eslint": true
    },
    "terminal.integrated.tabs.enabled": true,
    "window.zoomLevel": 1
}
```